# Typescrip: How to set a function return an Array include only string and number

Tags: typescript

I new in `typescript`.

I have a function return an Array incude string and number.

```
const test =() => {
  return [1,2,3,'test']
}
```

I want something like:

```
const test =():string[]|number[] => {
  return [1,2,3,'test']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, but your type says the array with **either** be of strings **or** numbers. You want an array of the union type `string | number`:

```
const test = (): (string | number)[] => {
    return [1, 2, 3, "test"];
};
```

(If you didn't provide a return type annotation at all, that's the type TypeScript would infer from what you're returning.)

---

It's probably not the case for what you're doing, but **if** the array will **always** be exactly four elements long and have three numbers followed by a string, you could use a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) instead:

```
const test = (): [number, number, number, string] => {
    return [1, 2, 3, "test"];
};
```